# MySQL Beginner query help, movie and actors

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Demo Sakila database here: https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?route=/database/structure&db=sakila

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to get the following information from the mysql demo sakila database:

Need a query to list the title of the film, the number of actors in the film, and a list of the actors name

Like this for example

[output preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVDME.png)

Comment: What have you tried to get the result so far? Can you show your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW GROUP_CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as name, COUNT(a.actor_id) as num_actors, b.title as title FROM actor a, film b, film_actor c WHERE c.film_id = b.film_id and c.actor_id = a.actor_id GROUP BY title;
```

But like the others indicated, to try and try again will be your best way to learn something like this.
Here is a good reference / tutorial to look at

https://database.guide/how-to-return-query-results-as-a-comma-separated-list-in-mysql/